# Magento 2.3.5 - Category sorting is not saved when drag and drop

Tags: magento2.3, category, sort

When we change the sorting of subcategories, by drag and drop in the admin panel, these new sorting is not saved. When we refresh the page, it randomize all subcategories and there is no logic in the sorting.

How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was occured because all categories had position 0 in the database.

Running the following query solved the issue and drag/drop works fine:

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity` SET `position` = '1000'
```